# Robot framework - cmd automation

Tags: cmd, robotframework

I'm trying to log in to the database server with applications run there. I can login without any problems, however when I use any command it does not seem to work.

Whole testcase looks like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SSHLibrary

*** Variables ***
${IP}  IP
${user}  user
${password}  password
*** Test Cases ***
CMD
    Open connection  ${IP}
    login  ${user}  ${password}
    write  cd gtms/bin
    write  pwd
```

And I am expecting to get info about the location when I use pwd, but it is not working. I get this in LOG:

KEYWORD SSHLibrary . Write pwd
Documentation:
Writes the given `text` on the remote machine and appends a newline.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20170725 14:55:30.101 / 20170725 14:55:30.109 / 00:00:00.008
14:55:30.101    TRACE   Arguments: [ 'pwd' ]
14:55:30.109    INFO    pwd 
14:55:30.109    TRACE   Return: 'pwd\r\n'

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `Execute Command` instead of `Write`

Comment: Whenever I use `Execute Command` I get:

`KEYWORD SSHLibrary . Execute Command pwd
Documentation: 
Executes `command` on the remote machine and returns its outputs.
Start / End / Elapsed: 20170731 13:31:44.798 / 20170731 13:31:44.854 / 00:00:00.056
13:31:44.799 INFO Executing command 'pwd'. 
13:31:44.853 INFO Command exited with return code 0.`

Comment: So your command was successfully executed. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is with logging it. I added it to the next answer, but it is gone now. Mainly after creating variable 
    `${pwd}  execute command  pwd
     log ${pwd}` 
i get the default location after logging in and not the one that I'm using `cd gtms/bin`.